# Restricting type of companion object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, interface

I want to create an interface with a print method that will print a value followed by a suffix.
So:

```
interface Unitary<T>{
    val value: T
    fun print(){
        print(value)
        println(suffix)
    }
}

interface HasSuffix{
    val suffix: String
} 

inline class Centimeters(val value: Double): Unitary<Double>{
    companion object: HasSuffix{
        override val suffix = "cm"
    }
}
```

Currently I'm receiving the error:

> Unresolved reference: suffix

Is there a way to indicate that suffix will be declared on the companion object of any implementing interface?

Comment: What is the relation between those two interfaces? Is `Centimeters` supposed to implement it?

Comment: @Pawel: Yes, just edited it in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to indicate that suffix will be declared on the companion object of any implementing interface?

I don't think there is.

You can work around that with something like:

```
interface Unitary<T>{
    val value: T

    fun suffixProvider() : SuffixProvider

    fun print(){
        print(value)
        println(suffixProvider().suffix)
    }
}

interface SuffixProvider{
    val suffix: String
} 

inline class Centimeters(override val value: Double): Unitary<Double>{
    companion object: SuffixProvider{
        override val suffix = "cm"
    }

    override fun suffixProvider() = Centimeters

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force subclasses to provide particular functionality namely via companion objects. Instead, you can force them provide a particular methods. How the classes implement this method is up to them.